# How to convert string with GMT to date in Athena

Tags: sql, datetime, amazon-athena, presto, trino

I have a column filled with dates in string format, e.g. `2023-01-31 11:21:33 GMT`.

I am trying to write a query that will select a year and a month and will do some calculations later on. My standard approaches using `EXTRACT(YEAR FROM a))` etc. did not work. Therefore, I am trying to parse datetime using `PARSE_DATETIME(a, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss')`. The thing is, I don't know how to format "GMT" and google did not help with that.

The error message is `INVALID_FUNCTION_ARGUMENT: Invalid format: "2023-01-31 11:21:33 GMT" is malformed at "GMT"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z'`:

```sql
select parse_datetime('2023-01-31 11:21:33 GMT', 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z')
```

Output:

| _col0 |
| --- |
| 2023-01-31 11:21:33.000 UTC |

`parse_datetime` is [Java date function](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html#java-date-functions) which uses  [JodaTime’s DateTimeFormat pattern format](https://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html) which is mostly compatible with `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` with `z` matching [general timezone](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#timezone).

Comment: This works! But now the format is malformed at "BST". A quick google search suggests that it might be more complicated. Any way to include it in this solution? I tried replacing z, with ZZZ but it gives me the same error message.

Comment: @bajun65537 TBH - don't know. There is a chance you will need to create some kind of table with mapping from `BST` to parsable timezone (I believe it should be `'Europe/London'` in this case). You can use `try` (i.e. `try(parse_datetime(...))`) to ignore and/or analyze all "invalid" record.